# Why is my button not showing in my subview?

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

I'm implementing a drawer cell. I'm configuring it now with some custom buttons I want. Unfortunately, the buttons aren't showing.

Thanks for the help

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        HHPanningTableViewCell *cell = (HHPanningTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        NSInteger directionMask = indexPath.row % 5;
        if (cell == nil) {
            NSLog(@"Cell = nil.");
            cell = [[HHPanningTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];




            UIView *drawerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];

            drawerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            cell.drawerView = drawerView;
                UIImage *checkImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"];
                UIButton *checkButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
                [checkButton setImage:checkImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [drawerView addSubview:checkButton];


                //[checkButton addTarget:nil action:(deleteListItem:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];



        // Configure the cell...

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part where you say `cell.frame`, I believe.  Try doing `CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)`.  I also don't see you giving a frame to the button?  `checkbutton.frame = CGRectMake(...);`

Answer (score 0):

you never set a frame for your button